# How do I recompute web2py's password hash?

Tags: authentication, web2py

I am trying to have another application (running on a different stack) authenticate with an existing application of mine that runs of web2py. I am trying to understand how can I validate the entered password with the one that I have in auth_user?

I did see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/tLAiqRaXG48 but I was unable to get the has from there. Here is what I am doing:

import hashlib
from pbkdf2 import crypt
crypt(hashlib.sha512("MyPassword").hexdigest(),iterations=1000)

My password in the db reads like this :

pbkdf2(1000,20,sha512)$b787f1e6dfe7da8f$b280b42a152aa14a1944d35c6a070521251b85d1

(slightly changed the hash itself)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rajaram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the value stored in the password field is not just the final hashed value but includes the algorithm, the per-user salt, and the final hashed value (all delimited by the $ symbol). So, assuming we have:

```
stored_password = 'pbkdf2(1000,20,sha512)$b787f1e6dfe7da8f$b280b42a152aa14a1944d35c6a070521251b85d1'
```

start by doing something like:

```
_, salt, hashed_password = stored_password.split('$')
```

Now, because pbkdf2 was used, we must use `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` to compare the hashes:

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
entered_password = 'MyPassword'
is_match = hashed_password == pbkdf2_hmac('sha512', entered_password, salt,
                                          rounds=1000, dklen=20).encode('hex')
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind copying the web2py validators.py module to the other system, you can simply do:

```
from validators import CRYPT
is_match = CRYPT()(entered_password)[0] == stored_password
```

Note, `CRYPT()` is a callable object (like all the web2py validators). When you call it with the entered password, it returns a tuple, the first element of which is a `LazyCrypt` object. The `LazyCrypt` class has implemented its own `__eq__` special method, so the `==` comparison above triggers that method. It automatically extracts the digest algorithm, salt, and hash from `stored_password`, computes the hash of `entered_password`, and compares that to the hash extracted from `stored_password` (i.e., everything that was done manually in the solution above).

Comment: To actually obtain the hash value using the `CRYPT()` method, simply convert it to a string, i.e. `str(CRYPT()(entered_password)[0])`